# What is the "database compatible mode" in Magento?

Tags: database, configuration

I've run over some comment in a core file which is about *database compatible mode*:

In `www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php`:

```
class Mage_Core_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

    # ...

    /**
     * Check whether database compatible mode is used (configs enable it for MySQL by default).
     *
     * @return bool
     */

    public function useDbCompatibleMode()
    {
        $connType = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_CONNECTION_TYPE);
        $path = 'global/resource/connection/types/' . $connType . '/compatibleMode';
        $value = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode($path);
        return (bool) $value;
    }

    # ...
```

This mode is new to me and I'm unable to find further references to it so I thought I put it here into Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything about it. Neither in MySQL context nor in PHP context. Maybe it is something very old implemented in MySQL several years ago?

More details:
If you search the magento source for `DbCompatibleMode`, you find:

```
\Mage_Core_Helper_Data::useDbCompatibleMode
```

Diggin deeper shows code fragments such as:

```
if (Mage::helper('core')->useDbCompatibleMode()) {
    $column['type']     = 'int';
    $column['is_null']  = true;
} else {
    $column['type']     = Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER;
    $column['nullable'] = true;
    $column['comment']  = 'Bundle Price View ' . $attributeCode . ' column';
}
```

But this still doesn't make sense. In `MySQL` `INT` and `INTEGER` are the synonyms. And in SQL92, INTEGER is the name of the row type, therefore this can't be a SQL92 compatibility mode.

Comment: I honor your comment, but it's placed as an answer which I think does not fit. Please move it into the comment section below the question.

Comment: I think this is the best answer you can get, therefore it is good where it is. If one gives a better one I'm ok deleting it

Comment: added more details, but still no satisfying answer

Comment: Well perhaps having a comment is unique to a certain database? It might have been that once other database types as Mysql were taken into consideration and that was meant by compatible?